# Doctrine fixtures ManyToOne - Faker don't loading

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, symfony4

I have tried to use faker to load some fixtures in my database and when I do
 `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load` for some reason that I don't know. The load  doesn't work and I don't have an error to explain me why it doesn't populate.If anyone can help me to just understand the problem ,it will be great.

Below you can see my code, it's datafixture for 2 entity with a relation many to one (tracker-position).

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;
use App\Entity\Positions;
use App\Entity\Tracker;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Faker;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;


class PositionsFixtures extends AbstractFixture implements ContainerAwareInterface ,FixtureInterface,OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    private $container;
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {

        $faker = Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR');
        $positions =[];
        for($i=0;$i < 5;$i++){
            $positions[$i] = new Positions();
            $positions[$i]->setTracker($faker->name);
            $positions[$i]->setCreationDate($faker->dateTime);
            $positions[$i]->setPositionDate($faker->dateTime);
            $positions[$i]->setState($faker->state);
            $positions[$i]->setLatitude($faker->latitude);
            $positions[$i]->setLongitude($faker->longitude);
            $positions[$i]->setSpeed($faker->numberBetween(0,400));
            $positions[$i]->setHeading($faker->numberBetween(0,360));
            $positions[$i]->setAddress($faker->address);
            $positions[$i]->setRawDate($faker->text);

            $manager->persist($positions[$i]);

        }

        $trackers =[];
        for($k=0;$k < 5;$k++){
            $trackers[$k] = new Tracker();
            $trackers[$k]->setName($faker->name);
            $trackers[$k]->setTrackerId($faker->uuid);
            $trackers[$k]->setEquipmentType($faker->realText());
            $trackers[$k]->setPlate($faker->randomLetter);
            $trackers[$k]->setDescription($faker->text);
            $trackers[$k]->setPhoneNumber($faker->phoneNumber);
            $trackers[$k]->setLastState($faker->state);
            $trackers[$k]->setLastConnectionDate($faker->dateTime);
            $trackers[$k]->setLastIp($faker->ipv4);
            $trackers[$k]->setLastPort($faker->numberBetween(100,80000));
            $trackers[$k]->setLastBatteryLevel($faker->numberBetween(0,100));
            $trackers[$k]->setLastLatitude($faker->latitude);
            $trackers[$k]->setLastLongitude($faker->longitude);
            $trackers[$k]->setLastHeading($faker->numberBetween(0,360));
            $trackers[$k]->setImage($faker->imageUrl());
            $trackers[$k]->setEnabled($faker->boolean);
            $randomPositions =(array) array_rand($positions,rand(1,count($positions)));
            foreach($randomPositions as $key => $value){

                $trackers[$k]->addPosition($positions[$key]);
            }
            $manager->persist($positions[$i]);

        }
        $manager->flush();
    }
   public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your command and result in your terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

With this link : https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-doctrine/faker-fixtures

I think you need review your code into DataFixtures, or you can use directly fixtures from Doctrine : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html